# OnListItemClick is never called?

Tags: java, android, cursor, adapter

I don't think this problem is caused from my ListActivity subclass. I think it has something to do with with my BaseAdapter subclass:

```
package com.mohit.gtodo;

import com.mohit.gtodo.database.TasksDBAdapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TasksCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public TasksCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    CheckBox completed = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.completed);
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

    title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksDBAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
    completed.setChecked(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksDBAdapter.KEY_COMPLETED)) > 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    return view;
}

}
```

Am I forgetting a method override?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a CheckBox, which is a clickable item. When a row contains a clickable item, the row cannot be clicked anymore. Instead of using checkboxes, use ListView's choiceMode attribute.

Comment: Should it be set to multipleChoice?

Comment: Then what event should we listen for, on the listview?